# how can I get a specific value from an array that comes as response from server

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a mongoDB which is saving the name of some places plus its coordinates, I'm trying to retrieve those coordinates so I can show the location in google maps in frontend, but I can't get the specific data that I need which is the coordinates, I have no idea how to do it, I've researched here but no luck, I've only made poor tries with no results.

**Fetch**

```
export const getRestoFetch = (endpoint, touken)=> {    
    
    let bearer = 'Bearer ' + touken;          
        
      return fetch(endpoint, {
        method: "GET",           
        headers:{          
          'Authorization': bearer
        }
        }).then(res =>{              
          if(res.status==200) {    
            
            res.json().then((data) => {console.log(data)});                  
  
          }else res.json().then((data) => {alert(data.message)});
        
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
        /* .then(response => console.log(response)); */
  }
```

what I get in console is:

```
Object {
  "restaurants": Array [
    Object {
      "__v": 0,
      "_id": "61060b1a535a37125cda3697",
      "_meals": Array [],
      "address": "Av Fuerzas Armadas",
      "createdAt": "2021-08-01T02:46:50.886Z",
      "description": "some randome street",
      "location": Object {
        "coordinates": Array [
          -75.630343,
          45.347986,
        ],
        "formattedAddress": "[3000 - 3199] Armada Ave, MADAS, Leitrim, ON K1T, CA",
        "type": "Point",
      },
      "meals": Array [],
      "name": "pizzatorio",
      "type": "de pizzas",
      "url": "no url",
    }
```

I want to get those coordinates, I tried `console.log(data.coordinates)` but this returns undefined. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get coordinates you have to use:

```
data.restaurants[0].location.coordinates
```

`console.log(data.restaurants[0].location.coordinates)` will give you the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

To get the current coordinates you have provided as an example:

```
data.restaurants[0].location.coordinates
```

That is due to coordinates being a field member of the location object, which an element in the restaurants array, which itself is a field member of data object.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest using async await but you need to understand how Promises work in any case.
As an example your function would be something like this

```
  export const getCoordinates = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(
      url
    ).then((res) => res.json());

    // if you wamt to use the data inside the function
    console.log(data.restaurants[0].location.coordinates);


    return data.restaurants[0].location.coordinates;
  };
```

Because I see you have **export** then it looks like you want to make a function for API requests for getting your data, then you need to use what the function returns also inside async functions like

```
 const useData = async () => {
    const data = await getCoordinates();

    console.log(data);
  };
```

Comment: That is absolutely right sir,  I came back for what you are pointing out here. I'd like to discuss this further but since this is not the topic of the post I think I need to make a new question, or may I ask here but editing the first post?

Comment: Ask a different question but firs search if it has been asnwered already so we avoid duplicates.